# How to match dynamically imported images from a local JSON file with a dynamic fetch from an API using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am building a Card and inserting some data that I fetch from an API. I want to insert some images to the card, but since the API doesn't provide images, I want to use my own local images. I put them into a json file to import them to the card. I was able to do it so, but now I can not make them to match their specific card. All I can do is put all of them together inside all cards mapped. How can I map the images inside the json file so I can have each image inside its respective card?

Here is my component where I fetch the API:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as C from './styles';

import api from '../../helpers/dnd5eAPI';

import { Theme } from '../../components/Theme';
import RaceCard from '../../components/RaceCard';

export const Races = () => {

    const [races, setRaces] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getRaces = async () => {
            const race = await api.getRaces();
            setRaces(race.results);
        };
        getRaces();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Theme>
            <C.Container>
                {races.map((item, index) => (
                    <RaceCard
                        key={index}
                        data={item}
                    />
                ))}
            </C.Container>
        </Theme>
    );
};
```

Here is the Card Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Markdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';
import * as C from './styles';

import images from '../../imagedata.json';

const RaceCard = ({ data }) => {

    return (
        <C.Container>
            <C.Card
                id={data.name}
            >
                <C.Content>
                    <C.Title>
                        {data.name}
                    </C.Title>
                    <C.Text>
                        <Markdown>{data.desc}</Markdown>
                    </C.Text>
                    <C.Button>
                        Read More
                    </C.Button>
                </C.Content>
                {images.map((item) => (
                    <C.Image
                        key={item.id}
                        imgsrc={item.imgsrc}
                        slug={item.slug}
                    >
                        <img src={item.imgsrc} />
                    </C.Image>
                ))}
            </C.Card>
        </C.Container>
    );
};

export default RaceCard;
```

Here is the JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "imgsrc": "/assets/races/dwarf.png",
    "slug": "dwarf"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "imgsrc": "/assets/races/elf.png",
    "slug": "elf"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "imgsrc": "/assets/races/halfling.png",
    "slug": "halfling"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "imgsrc": "/assets/races/human.png",
    "slug": "human"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "imgsrc": "/assets/races/dragonborn.png",
    "slug": "dragonborn"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "imgsrc": "/assets/races/gnome.png",
    "slug": "gnome"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "imgsrc": "/assets/races/halfelf.png",
    "slug": "half-elf"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "imgsrc": "/assets/races/half-orc.png",
    "slug": "half-orc"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "imgsrc": "/assets/races/tiefling.png",
    "slug": "tiefling"
  }
]
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I came up with an approach, but now I am not sure how is the proper syntax for what I want. I have imgsrc in my JSON file changed to the slug value, since I can fetch this from the API. Such as `"dwarf": "/assets/races/dwarf.png"`. When I pass the value to the src prop in the RaceCard component, I am trying to combine with the slug that I fetch from the API and match with the JSON File.  `<img src={item.dwarf} />`. How can I make the dwarf name to be replaced with the slug data that I fetch from the API. I can access the slug with `{data.slug}`. What syntax or logic should I use? Thanks.